# Issues using |replace with array as replacement

Tags: twig

I'm running into issues when trying to use the |replace function in Twig. I'm trying to display another value depending on a previous value.

```
{{ Results.Offer._symbol_at_attributes. Type|replace({'CP': '{{ Results.Offer._symbol_at_attributes.Packagesell}}','DP': '{{ Results.Offer._symbol_at_attributes.Sellprice }}'})}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Results` is a variable you don't need to add quotes around it. Adding quotes around it will turn into a string. Also the `{{ ... }}` should only be used to output things. The correct snippet would be,

```
{{ Results.Offer._symbol_at_attributes. Type|replace({'CP': Results.Offer._symbol_at_attributes.Packagesell,'DP': Results.Offer._symbol_at_attributes.Sellprice}) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, really appreciate it.